# How to save a copy of a state before it changes when using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to filter an array everytime a letter is entered into a searchbar but I was having trouble retaining the original array when I want to find another item. More specifically, the first time I try to filter using the searchbar it works but when I clear the searchbar and try to look for another item, the filtered array from the first time is still there. I know it is an issue with my useState hook but I'm not sure how to fix it. I also know I need to somehow save a copy of the unfiltered array before it is filtered but again I am not sure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', phoneNum: '040-123456', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', phoneNum: '39-44-5323523', id: 2 },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', phoneNum: '12-43-234345', id: 3 },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', phoneNum: '39-23-6423122', id: 4 }
  ])

  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
  const [newPhone, setNewPhone] = useState('');
  const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState('');
   
  const handleChange = (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      setNewName(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("Clicked submit btn")
    e.preventDefault();


    const newPerson = {
      name: newName,
      phoneNum: newPhone
    };

    if(persons.filter((person) => { return person.name === newPerson.name}).length > 0){
      alert(`${newName} already exists. Try another name.`);
    }
    else {
      setPersons(persons.concat(newPerson));
      console.log("persons array is now",persons)
    }
    setNewName("");
    setNewPhone("");
  }


   const searchLogic = (e) => {
    console.log("searchVal is",e.target.value);
    setSearchVal(e.target.value); //everytime the user selects a letter - the search value gets updated
  }

  useEffect(() => {

//filters persons array by the user-entered letters(searchVal)
    const filtered = persons.filter((person) => {
      return person.name.startsWith(searchVal); //array with matching results
    })

    if(filtered.length > 0){
      setPersons(filtered);
    }
    else {
      console.log(`We could not find a user by the name of ${searchVal}`)
    }
  },[searchVal])

//Works well for the first time, but the second time I try to look for another item, the old filtered array is still there

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <div className="searchfield">
        filter shown with a <input type="text" value={searchVal} onChange={searchLogic}/>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName}  onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          number: <input value={newPhone}  onChange={(e) => setNewPhone(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      {persons.map((person) => <p key={person.name}>{person.name} ---- {person.phoneNum}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a `useEffect` which overwrites your state with the filtered array, keep the full array in state the whole time. The filtered array is a derived value, which can be calculated based on the full array and the search term during rendering.

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', phoneNum: '040-123456', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', phoneNum: '39-44-5323523', id: 2 },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', phoneNum: '12-43-234345', id: 3 },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', phoneNum: '39-23-6423122', id: 4 }
  ])

// ...
const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState('');

// ... no useEffect

const filtered = persons.filter((person) => {
  return person.name.startsWith(searchVal);
})

return (
  <div>
    // ...
    {filtered.map((person) => (
       <p key={person.name}>
         {person.name} ---- {person.phoneNum}
       </p>
     ))}
  </div>
);
```

To improve performance, `useMemo` can be used to skip the calculation if nothing has changed.

```
const filtered = useMemo(() => {
  return persons.filter((person) => {
    return person.name.startsWith(searchVal);
  })
}, [searchVal, persons]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every change on searchVal you're filtering the state and then setting it, making it shorter every time. What you wanna do here is create *filtered* as a derivated data from persons state and do a map on this data.

```
{filtered.map((person) => <p key={person.name}>{person.name} ---- {person.phoneNum}</p>)}
```

You can also use a useMemo here to skip some unrelated renders

```
const filtered = useMemo(() => 
  persons.filter((person) => 
    person.name.startsWith(searchVal);
  ), [searchVal, persons]);
```

I'd rename *filtered* to a more descriptive name and there also a small problem here:

```
setPersons(persons.concat(newPerson));
      console.log("persons array is now",persons)
```

setState is async and here you're logging just after you call it, making it return an old state, if you wanna see most updated state value you need to run a console.log inside a useEffect that has state as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple solution would be to create a new variable through `useState` which always contains your filtered `persons` array. This way you keep `persons` as your "repository" and, let's say, `filteredPersons` as your displayed data, even when you don't have anything to filter on.

So your code could look like :

```
const [filteredPersons, setFilteredPersons] = useState(persons);

...

useEffect(() => {
    //filters persons array by the user-entered letters(searchVal)
    const filtered = persons.filter((person) => {
      return person.name.startsWith(searchVal); //array with matching results
    })

    setFilteredPersons(filtered);
    if(filtered.length == 0){
      console.log(`We could not find a user by the name of ${searchVal}`)
    }
  },[searchVal, persons])
```

And then use `filteredPersons` in your render function.

**Note** : Since your effect is dependent on persons, you must add it to the array of dependencies of `useEffect`

Hope this helps!